# Perl one-liner: Strip path from array to get only last name in path like basename

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to challenge myself to get the names of dir or files in a directory and put them into an array with the least amount of code as possible. I got all the pieces but can't put them together

perl glob: `<path/to/dir/*>`

regex replace: `s/.+\///`

my lame attempt to how I thought it would work:

```
my @flist = <path/to/dir/*>
s/.+\/// for @flist;
```

But I guess not.

Little help from a perl master?

Gracias!

Edit: I guess the above code just needed a semi-colon. N00b mistake. sorry! although it is still technically on two lines.

Comment: What do you get that you do not want?

Comment: _I'm trying to challenge myself..._ By asking others to do it? :>

Comment: @TLP I get syntax error.

Comment: @byrondrossos lol I failed the challenge, instead of doing the way I could hack it together, i want to learn how to do it because I know it IS possible. I failed :(

Comment: @dlite922 Well, you *do* have a missing semi-colon.. is that it? I can only guess, since "syntax error" is such a vague description of your error. You are using `use strict; use warnings;` right?

Comment: holy crap, it did work with a semi-colon. can't believe that worked! I typed that as an example of what I wanted, it wasn't my actual code. LOL

Comment: @dlite922 Next time, include the error right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all that is necessary is

```
my @flist = map m|([^/]+)$|, <path/to/dir/*>;
```

Comment: Changed answer to best answer because of exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
@flist = map basename($_), @flist;
```

or

```
$_ = basename($_) for @flist;
```

---

Since number of lines is important to you, the following is a neat combination of the line for which you asked and the line you already have:

```
my @flist =  map basename($_), <path/to/dir/*>;
```

Comment: I picked your as the answer because its the the cleanest one-liner, although it is technically two lines if you include "use File::basename"

Comment: Why do you care if it's two lines instead of one?

Comment: @dlite922, You can put `use File::Basename;` (and `use strict;` and `use warnings;`) on the same line if you think there's any value to having a one-liner.

Comment: @dlite922, Updated answer to show how to combine two of your lines.

Comment: Thanks. Looks clean! 
By the way, I'm a Java/PHP-OOP developer. Perl is turning my world upside down!

Comment: @dlite922, This particular style of programming is called "functional programming". Lisp, Scheme, Haskell and Erlang are examples of functional programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be functional, albeit a bit crude. You might consider using a module for stripping the path, such as [File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aBasename) (core module). An even simpler way is to make sure paths are not included at all.

You can simply move to the dir and use a glob there. Do remember that afterwards your working directory is changed.

```
chdir "/path/to/dir";
my @flist = <*>;
```

You can also use [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) and [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html). Note that this will return more files than `glob`, including hidden ones.

```
opendir my $dh, "/path/to/dir" or die $!;
my @flist = readdir $dh;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all hidden files (including dot and dot-dot) you can do:

```
chdir /mypath or die "$!\n";
my @list = glob(".* *");
```

See [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

Since you have changed into the diretory of interest, only the file names are reported without paths.  To skip reporting the dot and dot-dot files, but to see other hidden (dot) ones, you can do:

```
for (@list) {
    next if m{^\.\.?$};
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```perl
my @flist=glob('/usr/include/*.h');
s/.*\///g for @flist;
print join ("\n",@flist);
```